# Pull Request Flow

Tags: bitbucket, branching-strategy, bitbucket-cloud, merge-strategy

I want to implement branching strategy in bitbucket-cloud where a pull request to master can be done only from release/* branch and hotfix/* branch. No one branches would be allowed to raise a Pull request to master. 
Similarly a Pull request to Release/* branch can be done only from feature/* branches.

I have already enabled branching model for the same. Under Branch permission i am unable to control the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Got feedback for the same from bitbucket. Such flow is not available.